# Changing font in PDF file exported by AmCharts

Tags: javascript, pdf, amcharts, pdfmake

I'm having some difficulty navigating the AmCharts documentation. The major problem I seem to be running into is finding information on changing the default font when the pdf file is being created through the export, which is built into the licensed AmCharts version 3.20.3. I want it to be Open Sans and not Roboto (the pdfMake default).

```
export : {
                enabled : true,
                drawing : {
                    menu : [{
                        class : 'export-drawing',
                        menu : [{
                            label : translations['ADD'] + ' ...',
                            menu : [{
                                label : translations['PDF_ANNOTATE_SHAPE']  +' ...',
                                action : 'draw.shapes'
                            }, {
                                label : translations['PDF_ANNOTATE_TEXT'],
                                action : 'text'
                            }]
                        }, {
                            label : translations['PDF_ANNOTATE_CHANGE'] + ' ...',
                            menu : [{
                                label : translations['PDF_ANNOTATE_MODE'] + ' ...',
                                action : 'draw.modes'
                            }, {
                                label : translations['PDF_ANNOTATE_COLOR'] + ' ...',
                                action : 'draw.colors'
                            }, {
                                label : translations['PDF_ANNOTATE_SIZE'] + ' ...',
                                action : 'draw.widths'
                            }, {
                                label : translations['PDF_ANNOTATE_OPACITY'] + ' ...',
                                action : 'draw.opacities'
                            }, 'UNDO', 'REDO']
                        }, {
                            label : translations['PDF_EXPORT'],
                            format : 'PDF',
                            fileName : translations['MY_TEAM_PS'],
                            content : [
                                {
                                    image : 'reference',
                                    alignment : 'center',
                                    fit : [769.89, 523.28] // fit image to A4
                                },
                                reportDataTable
                            ],
                            pageOrientation : 'landscape',
                            styles : {
                                tableHeader : {
                                    fontSize : 8,
                                    bold : true
                                },
                                subheader : {
                                    fontSize : 12,
                                    bold : true
                                },
                                tableCell : {
                                    fontSize : 8,
                                    bold : false
                                },
                                quote : {
                                    italics : true
                                },
                                small : {
                                    fontSize : 8
                                }
                            }
                        }, 'CANCEL']
                    }]
                },
```

Their documentation seems to suggest that I should simply be able to add pdfMake : {} just inside of export and then do what I need to do there to change the font. Based on the documentation for pdfMake, it seems like I would need to do something along the lines of this:

```
export : {
                pdfMake : {
                    fonts : {
                        OpenSans : {
                            normal : 'OpenSans-Regular.ttf',
                            bold : 'OpenSans-Semibold.ttf',
                            italics : 'OpenSans-Italic.ttf',
                            bolditalics : 'OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf'
                        }
                    }
                },
                enabled : true,
                drawing : {
                    menu : [{
                        class : 'export-drawing',
                        menu : [{
                            label : translations['ADD'] + ' ...',
                            menu : [{
                                label : translations['PDF_ANNOTATE_SHAPE']  +' ...',
                                action : 'draw.shapes'
                            }, {
                                label : translations['PDF_ANNOTATE_TEXT'],
                                action : 'text'
                            }]
                        }, {
                            label : translations['PDF_ANNOTATE_CHANGE'] + ' ...',
                            menu : [{
                                label : translations['PDF_ANNOTATE_MODE'] + ' ...',
                                action : 'draw.modes'
                            }, {
                                label : translations['PDF_ANNOTATE_COLOR'] + ' ...',
                                action : 'draw.colors'
                            }, {
                                label : translations['PDF_ANNOTATE_SIZE'] + ' ...',
                                action : 'draw.widths'
                            }, {
                                label : translations['PDF_ANNOTATE_OPACITY'] + ' ...',
                                action : 'draw.opacities'
                            }, 'UNDO', 'REDO']
                        }, {... etc}
```

Am I on the right track at all with this line of thought? I cannot seem to find anyone who has done this before, and it's quite confusing. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: I see a lot of people mentioning the vfs_fonts.js file, but it is a vendor file in the vendor directory, and as a general rule, we don't mess with vendor files. The pdfMake documentation mentions creating your own and a bunch of other steps, but I'm thinking that there must be a better way than tweaking vendor files or needing to create an entire new file just to do this one (seemingly) simple thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a custom `vfs_fonts.js` file which contains your fonts in base64. Bartek the creator of [pdfMake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) wrote a neat [step-by-step tutorial](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/wiki/Custom-Fonts---client-side) how to create that file.

Once you've created your custom font file, you need to include `pdfMake.js` manually into your HTML document and add your custom `vfs_fonts.js` file behind it. Then add a reference to `window.pdfMake.fonts` otherwise it uses it's default font definition of "Roboto".

```
<script src="./amcharts/plugins/export/libs/pdfMake/pdfMake.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="vfs_fonts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    pdfMake.fonts = {
        "Open Sans": {
            "normal": 'OpenSans-Regular.ttf',
            "bold": 'OpenSans-Bold.ttf',
            "italics": 'OpenSans-Italic.ttf',
            "bolditalics": 'OpenSans-BoldItalic.ttf'
        }
    }
</script>
```

Your custom font is ready to use, only missing thing is your export config adaption like following:

```
AmCharts.makeChart( {
    "export": {
        "enabled": true,
        "pdfMake": {
            defaultStyle: {
                font: "Open Sans"
            }
        },
    },
    ...
} );
```

In case you've some troubles generating the `vfs_fonts.js` file I've created one for you - [download vfs_fonts.js](http://benjaminmaertz.de/amcharts/36924522/vfs_fonts.js) (Used: https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans)

Comment: I can't "thumbs up" that because I still don't have enough rep, but that is a great answer.